# No save startup file or load factory settings option?

Tags: startup-file

I'm trying to save a default startup, and online tutorials say File > Save Startup File... but I do not find this option

[image]

Answer (score 2):

the new path is *File* > *Defaults* > *Save Startup File*

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you!!!